# git syntax for specifying remote tracking branch versus syntax for git pull, push, checkout etc

Tags: git, syntax

The syntax for a git pull command is git pull [remote] [branch] (note the space in-between remote name and branch name).  e.g.:

```
git pull origin v0
```

However, for another command the syntax is [remote]/[branch] (this time a '/' instead of a space to separate [remote] and [branch]):

```
git branch --set-upstream v0 origin/v0
```

This is confusing to me since 'origin/v0' is also the name of the "remote tracking branch" on my local machine.   e.g the command to list remote tracking branches:

```
git branch -r

  origin/master
* origin/v0
```

Yet even more confusing to me is that the command to list all local tracking branches and remote tracking branches uses the syntax of
[branch] (for local branches) and remotes/[remote]/[branch] for remote tracking branches.  E.g.:

```
git branch -a 

  master
* v0
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/origin/vo
```

My primary question is am I correctly understanding these seemingly ambiguous syntax conventions?

A second question and comment is: why have the ambiguity with respect to the different ways of referencing the remote tracking branches, such as is the case with origin/master versus remotes/origin/master?

Why not just have 'git branch -a' not prepend 'remotes/'?  e.g.:

```
 git branch -a 

      master
    * v0
     origin/master
    * origin/v0
```

And for functions like:

```
git branch --set-upstream v0 origin/v0
```

Make it:

```
git branch --set-upstream v0 origin v0
```

so that one knows the command argument is referencing a branch 'v0' of a remote named 'origin' and not the "remote tracking branch".

or even use a verbose named parameters syntax:

```
git branch --set-upstream OfLocalBranch:v0 ToRemoteAndBranch::origin v0
```

or some variation of the above named param approach.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in `git pull remote branch`, the `branch` does not correspond to a *remote* branch but to a *local* branch. Using that command will pull changes from the remote tracking branch of `branch` from the remote `remote` (although that behavior depends a bit on your settings). Nevertheless, using `git pull remote/branch` would not be a proper alternative there.

As for remote tracking branches, `remotes/<remote>/<branch>` is the *real* name of these branches. So when listing all branches, it just *has* to list the full name to avoid ambiguity and to make it clear that a branch is a remote branch. When using `git branch -r` however, you are explicitely requesting remote branches, so you know that all branches you will see are remote branches (with an implicit `remotes/` prefix). So Git will just show you the short names for these; because Git allows you to be imprecise and leave off parts if it can figure out which branch you mean.

When specifying a `<refname>`, Git will [try the following refs until it finds one](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html):

> 1. If `$GIT_DIR/<refname>` exists, that is what you mean (this is usually useful only for `HEAD`, `FETCH_HEAD`, `ORIG_HEAD`, `MERGE_HEAD` and `CHERRY_PICK_HEAD`);
> 2. otherwise, `refs/<refname>` if it exists;
> 3. otherwise, `refs/tags/<refname>` if it exists;
> 4. otherwise, `refs/heads/<refname>` if it exists;
> 5. otherwise, `refs/remotes/<refname>` if it exists;
> 6. otherwise, `refs/remotes/<refname>/HEAD` if it exists.

That list already shows you what the actual full names of references are:

- `refs/tags/<name>` for tags
- `refs/heads/<name>` for branches
- `refs/remotes/<name>` for remote branches

So all you do, like specifying just `master` is just a shortcut Git allows you to do, so you don’t have to specify it as `heads/master` (you still can though). And for remotes, usally, a prefix like `origin/` will not be used by non-remote branches, so specifying `origin/branch` is usually a safe guarantee that you are talking about a remote branch.

---

To answer one of your questions explicitely with an example: *“Why not just have `git branch -a` *not* prepend `remotes/`?”*

It’s perfectly fine to have a repository, which `git branch -a` returns the following output, of which only the last one is an actual remote branch:

```
$ git branch -a
* master
  origin/master
  remotes/origin/master
```

---

And as for specifying the remote *tracking* branch, using `git branch --set-upstream`, you need to know that you are *not* specifying a branch of some remote. You are indeed setting a remote *tracking* branch, which is why you need to reference that remote tracking branch there.

There is actually nothing—apart from convention—that requires remote tracking branches to be called `remotes/<remote>/<branch>`. It’s absolutely possible to have them named `foo/bar/baz/<branch>` instead, and they would still be updating with `git fetch`. Because the important thing is the remote configuration stored in the repository’s config file. Usually, such a section looks likes this:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@github.com:poke/myproject.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

This essentially tells Git to update the *remote branches* at `remotes/origin/*` for each branch found in the remote’s local branch list. As I said above, you could change that and make them stored somewhere else.

Comment: "First of all, in git pull remote branch, the branch does not correspond to a remote branch but to a local branch."

Comment: per your comment "First of all, in git pull remote branch, the branch does not correspond to a remote branch but to a local branch." - Yes I think that is what I said.  Pull causes a fetch & merge, and any newer commits to the 'remote branch' (in the remote repository)by others will be copied to the 'remote tracking branch', and then that remote tracking branch merged with the local tracking branch.

Comment: When I said "However, for another command the syntax is [remote]/[branch] (this time a '/' instead of a space to separate [remote] and [branch]):" I wasn't implying git pull remote/branch would be an alternate in the case of pull.  I did give some mention of alternates for other git functions

Comment: It does seem to me that Git really overloads its use of the term remote.  Things that are confusing:

Comment: Sorry but StackOverflow's 5 minute limit is causing me to have to post the comment twice. It does seem to me that Git really overloads its use of the term remote.  It is confusing that a read only tracking branch (repository) on the local machine is called "remote tracking branch" which to me implies it is on the remote machine.  Per remotes/<remote>/<branch>, it would be clearer to a beginner if all functions used the full name.

Comment: I looked at the rev page you referenced and I immediately don't understand what the 'number of commits' part of the following means?  (I can guess that it might mean that it will find a commit with that sha and then walk the list until it finds a match per the version number) "<describeOutput>, e.g. v1.7.4.2-679-g3bee7fb
Output from git describe; i.e. a closest tag, optionally followed by a dash and a number of commits, followed by a dash, a g, and an abbreviated object name."

Comment: correction: walk the rev graph until it finds a match per the version number)

Answer (score 0):

I see this is already answered but I am going to try something a bit different.

The basic issue here is that `git pull` is a very old command that was written before the whole idea of remote-tracking branches was complete and common.

#### Background

The first thing to remember with git (or indeed any modern distributed version control system) is that your repository is *yours*.  There really aren't any "remote branches", there are only local ones, in your repository.  The ones called "remote"—or, a slightly better name, "remote-tracking"—are stored locally, in *your* repository; they're merely *updated* when there's a chance, to match what your git sees in some remote repository.

That is, your `remotes/origin/master` is "a copy of what I, your git, saw on `master` last time I called up `origin` and asked his git what he had in `master`".  So it's your most recent copy of what is (or was) over there, the last time you checked.  To check again, you just run `git fetch origin`: your git uses its Internet-phone to call up their git and see what they have, and bring over things they have that you don't.  These also get updated when you `git push`, because that also has your git calling up their git to see what they have, and give them stuff you have that they don't.

(With git since about 1.8.2, this really is the case; with older versions, *some* invocations of `git fetch` fail to update your copy.  Annoyingly, it's *specifically* invocations as run by the `git pull` script.  But if your git is newer than that, this little wrinkle is gone, and the remote-tracking branch really is kept up to date whenever possible.)

#### History

With that out of the way, let's go back to `git pull`, and the history behind this.  Specifically, there is a point in time where there weren't even "remotes" at all.  If you were Linus Torvalds, or working with him, you ran `git fetch git://some.host.name/some/path develop`, because you knew who was working on what, what their host name was, and what branch or branches they were using.  This would connect to the named host and pick up the named branch, and dump all that information into a file named `FETCH_HEAD`.  Then you look in `FETCH_HEAD` and see what they've been doing, and maybe merge it into your own repository using an older, somewhat more raw merge command.

It turns out that this was really common, so someone wrote the `pull` script to do the fetch and then the merge.  And there were still no "remotes", so you just named the branch you knew Bob was using for development: your git called his up, asked for his by the branch name you just typed in, and then your git merged his stuff, from the `FETCH_HEAD` file that `git fetch` dumped everything into, into your current branch.

As a result, the branch name(s) given as argument(s) to `git pull` are, in fact, *not* local branch names at all, in gross violation of almost every other rule about git branch names.  Those names are handed to `git fetch` which in turn hands them off to the called-up git, over the Internet-phone (or whatever transport).  The resulting SHA-1 IDs are brought over and stuffed into your local `FETCH_HEAD` file (along with the names again).

#### Evolution

Once "remotes" were invented, with the idea of "remote-tracking branches" stored in your local repo, all of the old stuff should have been thrown out immediately, except of course people were used to it, and were using it and depended on that behavior.  So `git pull origin master` still works the way it has for many years, and still violates the rules.

Fortunately `git pull` simply figures out what the upstream remote is, and what the branch is on that remote, so running it *without* extra arguments uses the tracking info and just does the right thing automatically.  You store the URL once, under the appropriate remote name—and usually git does this for you on the initial clone—and from then on you never need to retype a long URL.

#### Issues

You can still run `git pull` with extra arguments, because backwards compatibility is actually important.  Alas, `git pull origin master develop` does not mean what most people expect it to mean: the `pull` script tells `fetch` to bring over the remote's `master` and `develop` and put *both* of them into `FETCH_HEAD`, and then it runs `git merge` to do an "octopus merge", merging both of the brought-over SHA-1 IDs with your current branch (which need not be either `master` *or* `develop`).

#### Refspecs

It's worth adding here that there are situations where you *do* need to specify both a local branch name, and a remote branch name.  Specifically, if you (locally) named a branch `fix-bug-123`, which is a good and sensible thing to do when you're fixing bug #123 on the `develop` branch, you may want to push your fix directly from there to `develop` on the remote (where the reviews will occur or where the product is built).  To do that, you specify a remote and then give a "refspec".

A refspec is, in short,<sup>1</sup> just a pair of branch names.  To push your `fix-bug-123` to their `develop`, you do:

```
$ git push them fix-bug-123:develop
```

Your local branch name goes on the left, and their remote branch name goes on the right.

You can do the same when fetching (remember, the opposite of `push` is `fetch`, *not* `pull`—`pull` is that historical script that does `fetch`-then-`merge`!), but here the names are reversed.  Suppose you have your own `develop` branch, but you've heard that Mr Jones has some nice stuff.  Instead of setting up a proper remote, you want to just quickly `fetch` from mrjones.com, getting his `feature` branch and calling it `jones-feature` in your repository:

```
$ git fetch git://mrjones.com/path/to/repo.git feature:jones-feature
[fetch stuff happens here]
$ git log jones-feature
```

It's probably *wiser* to create an actual remote instead, and fetch everything: the "less wise" method is just for illustration.  Here his branch name goes on the left and yours goes on the right, because it's always "source:destination".  With a fetch, the source is remote and the destination is local; with a push, the source is local, and the destination is remote.

The "wiser" way gets you a `remotes/mrjones/feature`:

```
$ git remote add mrjones git://mrjones.com/path/to/repo.git
$ git fetch mrjones
$ git log remotes/mrjones/feature
```

When you do it this way, git still uses fetch ref-specs, but it hides them in your `.git/config` file, under the `remote` entry for `mrjones`.  You can see them with `git config get-all`:

```
$ git config get-all remote.mrjones.fetch
```

(the `get-all` variant is in case you set up multiple `fetch` lines; by default, git just creates one fetch line, but I figured I should illustrate the most complex case here.)

---

<sup>1</sup>Slightly too short: this glosses over details of how tags work, for instance.  Unqualified ref-specs are matched up as needed, or created as branches.  To force something to be a tag, spell it out: `refs/tags/sometag`, for instance.  Anything spelled-out with `refs/` makes git work within that name-space.